# Can I turn this for loop into recursion or dynamic programming?

Tags: python

I am trying to make the code that I have into either recursion or dynamic programming.

```py
    import numpy as np

    index_list = [1, 2, 0]
    weights = [0.3, 0.8]
    A_matrix = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]])
    initial_best_vector = A_matrix[:, 1]

    # set best_vector_combinations to initial_best_vector
    best_vector_combinations = initial_best_vector
    for index, _ in enumerate(index_list[1:]):
        best_vector_combinations = (
            1 - weights[index]
        ) * best_vector_combinations + (
            weights[index] * A_matrix[:, index_list[index + 1]]
        )
```

Is it possible to do so? What I am doing is a nested linear combination of vectors, with the initial base being the `initial_best_vector`, which corresponds to the `index_list`.

In other words, let c_i be the columns of the matrix A, I want:

((1-0.3) * c_1 + 0.3 * c_2) * (1-0.8) + 0.8 * c_0

I hope to make this case more general to hold for any length of numbers.

---

Edit:

The code:

```py
def calculate(vectors, weights):
    if not (vectors or weights):
        return 0
    
    if not weights:
        return vectors[0] 
    
    return vectors[0]*(1-weights[0]) + weights[0] * (calculate(vectors[1:], weights[1:]))
```

```
vectors = [1,2,3]
weights = [0.2, 0.3]
calculate(vectors, weights) = 1.26
```

but expected answer is 1.74 where i would expect first case to be 0.8 * 1 + 0.2 * 2 = 1.2, then second to be 1.2 * 0.7 + 3 * 0.3 = 1.74. Note I replaced your typo `result` to `calculate` but still unable to recover 1.74.

Comment: What does "more general" mean? An answer can only be good as your definition (and your attempt to solve the actual problem, not just one that is tangentially related)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a recursive implementation, if would be helpful to start with a simpler example and figure out the recurrence relation.
Let `vectors = [8,5,2,1]` (1D array for simplicity) and let `weights = [0.5, 0.8, 0.1, 0.2]`.

First step of computation: `(8 * 0.5)` + `(1-0.5)*(result of second step)`.
Second step: `5 * 0.8` + `(1-0.8)*(result of third step)`.

You can work this out further, but the basic relation is

```
result(vectors, weights) = 
(
    vectors[0]*weights[0]) + 
    (1-weights[0]) * (result(vectors[1:], weights[1:]))
) if (vectors and weights) else 0
```

Implementation:

```py
def calculate(vectors, weights):
    if not (vectors or weights):
        return 0
    
    if not weights:
        return vectors[0] 
    
    return vectors[0]*weights[0] + (1-weights[0]) * (calculate(vectors[1:], weights[1:]))

print(calculate([1,2,3], [0.2,0.3])) #left to right processing, 1.26
print(calculate([1,2,3][::-1], [0.2,0.3][::-1])) #right to left processing, 1.74
```

Comment: That's not python and it's not clear how it solves OP's issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but notice that my weights is one less than the vectors, how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Thanks, I could not quite understand the part on if not weights, setting to vectors[0].

Comment: @ilovewt that's the case where no more weights are left, and one last vector is left. So we just return that last vector

Comment: Thanks, one more thing, I tried to debug but to no avail, but if put test cases vectors = [1,2,3]
weights = [0.2, 0.3], i would expect first case to be 0.8 * 1 + 0.2 * 2 = 1.2, then second to be 1.2 * 0.7 + 3 * 0.3 = 1.74. Note I replaced your typo `result` to `calculate` but still unable to recover 1.74.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect your code and my query.

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me 2.36 bu tnot 1.74

Comment: @ilovewt the entire function was modified, not just the print() command. Copy the function and try again